# Upgraded customization's user fields aren't populating in the grid

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to add user fields to the Employee Time Card screen (EP305000) grid area that's been working through several versions / upgrades - but now in version 20.102.0015 it fails to bring in the data into the user fields.

The user fields are defined as follows:

```
public class EPTimecardDetailExt : PXCacheExtension<EPTimecardDetail>
{
    #region UsrStartDate
    public abstract class usrStartDate : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBDateAndTime(DisplayNameDate = "Start Date", DisplayNameTime = "Start Time*", UseTimeZone = true)]
    //[PXDBTime(DisplayMask = "t", InputMask = "t")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start Time*")]
    public virtual DateTime? UsrStartDate { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region UsrEndDate
    public abstract class usrEndDate : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBDateAndTime(DisplayNameDate = "End Date", DisplayNameTime = "End Time*", UseTimeZone = true)]
    //[PXDBTime(DisplayMask = "t", InputMask = "t")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "End Time*")]
    public virtual DateTime? UsrEndDate { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region UsrRelatedCase
    public abstract class usrRelatedCase : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(10)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Related Case*")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<CRCase.caseCD,
                               InnerJoin<PMProject,
                                    On<CRCase.customerID, Equal<PMProject.customerID>>>,
                        Where<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Current<EPTimecardDetail.projectID>>>,
                        OrderBy<Desc<CRCase.caseCD>>>),
        typeof(CRCase.caseCD),
        typeof(CRCase.subject),
        typeof(CRCase.createdDateTime), 
        typeof(CRCase.caseClassID), 
        typeof(CRCase.status), 
        typeof(CRCase.contactID),
        typeof(CRCase.ownerID),
        DescriptionField = typeof(CRCase.subject))]
    //typeof(CRCase.status),
    //typeof(CRCase.priority),
    //typeof(CRCase.severity),
    //typeof(CRCase.caseClassID),
    //typeof(BAccount.acctName),
    //Filterable = true)]
    public virtual string UsrRelatedCase { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

The values are in the database - they save correctly - but they won't show up in the grid.
Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Have you attempted to remove the fields from the screen and then re-add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was provided by Acumatica support.

In my customization, I was creating a Cache Extension for a 'Projection' DAC, namely EPTimeCardDetail.  The solution was to create an extension of the DAC which represented the actual table to which the user fields were actually added, which is PMTimeActivity.

Once I created the Cache Extension to PMTimeActivity, the problem was solved and the values were displayed in the grid.

It is unknown why this worked fine in previous versions.

Comment: Thanks for posting this - it helped me out!  Going a step further, in order to get a FieldUpdated event to work for my custom field on EPTimecardDetail(PMTimeActivity), I had to add the field to both DAC's.  So, heads up to all.